# How do I mock methods of a decorated class in python?

Tags: python, python-unittest, patch

Having trouble with applying mocks to a class with a decorator.  If I write the class without a decorator, patches are applied as expected.  However, once the class is decorated, the same patch fails to apply.

What's going on here, and what's the best way to approach testing classes that may be decorated?

Here's a minimal reproduction.

```py
# module.py
import functools


def decorator(func):

    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper


@decorator  # comment this out and the test passes
class Something:

    def do_external(self):
        raise Exception("should be mocked")

    def run(self):
        self.do_external()
```

```py
# test_module.py
from unittest import TestCase
from unittest.mock import Mock, patch

from module import Something


class TestModule(TestCase):
    @patch('module.Something.do_external', Mock())
    def test_module(self):
        s = Something()
        s.run()
```

If you prefer, [here's an online reproducible example of the issue.](https://www.online-python.com/Z7YTU2fBat)

Comment: Because the name `module.Something` *no longer refers to your class*. Rather, it refers to the `wrapper` function you return from the decorator. So `module.Something.do_external` *doesn't actually exist*. What exactly does your `decorator` do? Most class decorators I've worked with return the actual class, or perhaps another class (which will have the attributes of the class being decorated), but not a function.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks for the reply, but you're wrong when you say `do_external` doesn't exist.  The decorator in the minimal repro simply calls the decorated class and returns that instance.  You can readily verify that the code calls `do_external` by commenting out the patch.

Comment: Sorry, they *exist at that name* because of the `wraps`, but they are being patched *on the function, not the class*. But the instance you return is still accessing everything through the class. The point is, `Something` **is not your class anymore despite the name**, it is a *function object*, not the class object

Answer (score 1):

So, as I stated in the comment, your wrapper function replaces `Something` in the `module` module namespace. So, putting your code in `module.py` on my computer, observe:

```
>>> import module
>>> type(module.Something)
<class 'function'>
```

Since you used the `functools.wraps` decorator, the object being wrapped is added to the wrapper function at `.__wrapped__`:

```
>>> module.Something.__wrapped__
<class 'module.Something'>
>>> type(module.Something.__wrapped__)
<class 'type'>
```

So when you patch `module.Something`, you are patching *the function object*, not the *class object*. But instances of your class directly reference the class internally, it doesn't *matter* what global name refers to it. So, observe some more:

```
>>> import unittest.mock as mock
>>> with mock.patch('module.Something.do_external', mock.Mock()):
...     print(module.Something.do_external)
...     print(module.Something.__wrapped__.do_external)
...
<Mock id='140609580169920'>
<function Something.do_external at 0x7fe23822cc10>
```

This is why we see this particular behavior:

```
>>> with mock.patch('module.Something.do_external', mock.Mock()):
...     module.Something().do_external()
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/Users/jarrivillaga/module.py", line 18, in do_external
    raise Exception("should be mocked")
Exception: should be mocked
```

In this particular case, because the `__wrapped__` attribute references the original class, we can patch that:

```
>>> with mock.patch('module.Something.__wrapped__.do_external', mock.Mock()):
...     module.Something().do_external()
...
<Mock name='mock()' id='140608505553680'>
```

But I highly suggest rethinking your decorator design, if this is meant for external/public use. But just fundamentally, `module.Something` **is not a class**, it is a *function*, so you cannot treat it like a class and expect it to work like a class.

Note, the fact that you used `wraps` makes it *possible* for the patch to work at all, although, **it just hides the problem** because putting those other functions as attributes of the wrapper function *don't really provide anything useful*. `wraps` is mostly meant to be used when wrapping *other functions*, where creating a new function that *looks* like the old function makes sense, in the case of a class, though, you are making a *function* look like a *class*, but only superficially. Just removing the `@wraps` line, observe:

```
>>> import module
>>> import unittest.mock as mock
>>> with mock.patch('module.Something.do_external', mock.Mock()):
...     pass
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/jarrivillaga/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/unittest/mock.py", line 1404, in __enter__
    original, local = self.get_original()
  File "/Users/jarrivillaga/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/unittest/mock.py", line 1377, in get_original
    raise AttributeError(
AttributeError: <function decorator.<locals>.wrapper at 0x7ff820081160> does not have the attribute 'do_external'
```

So `functools.wraps` here was just *hiding* a fundamental error.